# how to create a gradient in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css

How to create a gradient background like this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do it at the moment is to avail yourself of the [ColorZila Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). It will generate the appropriate -moz-linear-gradient and -webkit-gradient entries for you, along with the appropriate filter values for Internet Explorer. The interface is a lot like the gradient editor in programs like Photoshop & Paint Shop Pro.